# Invariants on the space of probability distributions

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

There are many valuable functionals on the space of probability distributions which are invariant under variable transformations. (as an example KL divergence) 
But all these functionals are defined on a pair of distributions.Are there any known invariant functionals (and useful) depending on one distribution (not pairs)

Some explanations.
In the case of the translation group we have a known set of invariants.
These are cumulants (from the second order).
In the case of a subgroup of the group of diffeomorphisms with Jacobian of the transformation=1 entropy of the distribution is example of an invariant.
So, interest is the case of the full group of diffeomorphisms

Reformulate the question.

Is the orbit any smooth distribution ( non constant) under group diffeomorphisms coincides with the space of all smooth distributions ?
If so, that non-trival invariants are absent.

Comment: the normalisation constant? I can't imagine any other invariant.

Comment: For finite discrete distributions, the answer is obvious: There are N independent invariants, where each invariant is equal to one of values of probability functions (>0)

Comment: What transformations do you want to be invariant to?

Comment: I mean the invariance under the group of diffeomorphisms of feature space (let R^n for definiteness)
Exactly this group is meant in the case of KL divergence.

Answer (score 3):

See the following paper:

- Martin Bauer, Martins Bruveris, Peter W. Michor: Uniqueness of the Fisher-Rao metric on the space of smooth densities. Bulletin of the London Mathematical Society. 48, 3 (2016), 499-506 [(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/Fisher-Rao-metric.pdf)

The proof shows that only the total volume is invariant under the whole diffeomorphism group: For probability distributions only the constants. 
In a followup paper (not finished) all Diff-invarinat tensor fields are determined. For the results see the [slides](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/Liblice-Fisher-Rao.pdf) of a talk.

Comment: Does that mean that the orbit  any smooth distribution ( non constant) under group diffeomorphisms coincides with the space of all distributions ?

Comment: This is Moser's theorem.

Comment: As I understand the theorem of Moser implies strict positivity of probability distributions. Is there any reasoning to the case when  distribution may be eual zero in some areas of the feature space ?

Comment: No. You will have many Diff-orbits. The diffeotopy type of the zero set is an invariant then.

Comment: I understand. The invariants will also be of values of volume form  on the connected pieces of  "no zero set".